# Взаимодействие между окнами Java Fx

Tags: java, javafx, gui, ui

как при нажатии на кнопку перейти на новую страницу (класс-контроллер и fxml розметка)?

Comment: имеется в виду модальное окно? или основной stage заменить другой вьюхой?

Comment: основной stage заменить другой вьюхой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ManyScenes extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("mainScene.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    public void changeScene() {
         // Загружаем новую сцену и задаем эту сцену primaryStage

         // Еще перед переключением можно сделать 
         // primaryStage.hide(); 

         Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("secondScene.fxml"));
        Scene second= new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(second);

        // обязательно если вызывается hide() перед этим.
        // primaryStage.show();

    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

```
@FXML
void shar_history(ActionEvent event) { // название моей кнопки
    win_arh(); // вызываем новое окно
    shar_history.getScene().getWindow().hide(); // закрываем текущее окно
}

    public void win_arh(){
    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Arh.fxml")); // название FXML которое надо открыть
        Parent root1 = fxmlLoader.load();
        Stage stage1 = new Stage();
        stage1.setScene(new Scene(root1, 1302, 805)); // размеры нового окна
        stage1.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

ну а в самом FXML файле указывается класс-контроллер

Comment: кто ж Вас научил так методы называть?

Comment: и не знаю где вы взяли такой код - не совсем корректен он.

Comment: что именно некорректно?

Comment: зачем плодить кучу stage-ов если один главный, который дается при запуске приложения.